# Powershell : Add new XML element after a specific current sibling element

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml list that I wish to add a new child element to under `<game>`. I have been able to appended the child element to the end of the game node block but for naming standards I need to insert it after the image element as a sibling of image.

```
<image>
<marquee>
```

XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <gameList>
      <game id="2758" source="theGamesDB.net">
          <path>./Zelda II - The Adventure of Link (USA).zip</path>
          <name>Zelda II - The Adventure of Link (USA)</name>
          <desc>Removed description for example</desc>
          <image>./boxart/Zelda II - The Adventure of Link (USA).png</image>
          <rating>0.68333</rating>
          <releasedate>19880926T000000</releasedate>
          <developer>Nintendo</developer>
          <publisher>Nintendo</publisher>
          <genre>Action</genre>
          <players>1</players>
      </game>
</gamelist>
```

My code to append a marquee child element at the end of the code block. 
*Note: This is a for each loop that cycles through a huge list of games. For simplicity I have taken out the code that creates the marquee path location and hard coded it in.*

```
#Set the name of the game list 
    $InputXML = "gamelist.xml"
    $OutputXML = "MODgamelist.xml"

    #Load the existing document
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $InputXML

    foreach($game in $xml.gamelist.game)
    {

    #Set Marquee Path
    $marqueelPath = "./Zelda II - The Adventure of Link (USA).png"

    #Add marquee node to game node parent
    $marqueeElement = $xml.CreateElement("marquee") 
    $marqueeElement.InnerText = $marqueelPath
    $game.AppendChild($marqueeElement)   

    }

    #Output
    $xml.save($OutputXML)
```

After some digging I have come up with this code to insert the new child element after image but it errors out. How do I correctly select the image node then insert after it?

```
$imageElement = $game.SelectSingleNode('//image')
$game.InsertAfter($marqueeElement, $imageElement)
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "InsertAfter" with "2" argument(s): "The reference node is not a child of this node."
At line:1 char:1
+ $game.InsertAfter($marqueeElement, $imageElement)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `$imageElement.ParentNode.InsertAfter($marqueeElement, $imageElement)`?

Comment: Hi Har07, Thank you for your suggestion. Problem is it added it as a child of image. Sorry if I did not explain that well in my post. I have edited it. I want <marquee> to be a sibling of <image> and be inserted right after it.

Comment: That's what that line supposed to do, if I didn't miss anything: add `$marqueeElement` as child of `$imageElement.ParentNode`, right after `$imageElement`.

Comment: You have to remove the `//` in your SelectSingleNode method, otherwise you will always get the image of the first game @SamuelMeddows

Comment: @J.Bergmann You should post that as an answer

Comment: @J.Bergmann I did some testing of your suggestion and get the same resulting output of having either '//image' or just 'image'.

Comment: @SamuelMeddows Could you update the snippet in your question or add your testing snippet to show where/how exactly you try to get the image node?

Answer (score 2):

I was reading through the MSDN documentation and worked out a solution. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k44daxya.aspx

With all the Game Node blocks being identical in layout, I can actually call the reference node by array number.

```
#Add marquee node to game node parent
$marqueeElement = $xml.CreateElement("marquee") 
$marqueeElement.InnerText = $marqueelPath
$game.InsertAfter($marqueeElement, $game.ChildNodes[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a year old post, and I don't see an accepted answer on this one, but @har07's suggestion worked for me in the above comments. You want the two nodes to be children of the same parent element, with one inserted right after the other. First, you need to get the parent node and then call the InsertAfter(newNode, refNode) method on the parent node which worked for me. using OP's code:

```
$ParentNode = $imageElement.ParentNode
$ParentNode.InsertAfter($marqueeElement, $imageElement)
```