# How to add new element for XML in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I haven't worked that much with XML in Powershell and I can't make it work, so hope there is someone who can help

I have this XML file, and want to add a new element name ExitProcess below the element name ExitProcesses

How do you add that?

I want to go from this

````
```
<ExitProcesses>
<ExitProcess>
  <ProcessName>outlook.exe</ProcessName>
  <ForceClose>False</ForceClose>
</ExitProcess>
</ExitProcesses>

```
````

To this

````
```
<ExitProcesses>
<ExitProcess>
  <ProcessName>outlook.exe</ProcessName>
  <ForceClose>False</ForceClose>
</ExitProcess>
<ExitProcess>
  <ProcessName>Test.exe</ProcessName>
  <ForceClose>False</ForceClose>
</ExitProcess>
</ExitProcesses>

```
````

Comment: Did you try to search for it first?  [powershell  add new element XML](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D++add+new+element+XML)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell : Add new XML element after a specific current sibling element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251924/powershell-add-new-xml-element-after-a-specific-current-sibling-element)

Comment: Yes I have searched for it. I can add elements, just not under the specific place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to construct the new subtree:

```xml
<ExitProcess>
  <ProcessName>outlook.exe</ProcessName>
  <ForceClose>False</ForceClose>
</ExitProcess>
```

So we need to:

- Create an `<ExitProcess>` node
- Create a `<ProcessName>` node

  - Add it as a child of `<ExitProcess>`
- Create a `<ForceClose>` node

  - Add it as a child of `<ExitProcess>` / sibling of `<ProcessName>`

Let's create a small function to do this:

```
function New-ExitProcessNode
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [xml]$Document,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$ProcessName,

    [switch]$ForceClose
  )

  # Create ExitProcess node
  $exitProcessNode = $Document.CreateElement('ExitProcess')

  # Create ProcessName node, add process name as inner text
  $processNameNode = $Document.CreateElement('ProcessName')
  $processNameNode.InnerText = $ProcessName

  # Create ForceClose node, add setting as inner text 
  $forceCloseNode = $Document.CreateElement('ProcessName')
  $ForceCloseNode.InnerText = $ForceClose.IsPresent

  # Add the child nodes to the ExitProcess node
  [void]$exitProcessNode.AppendChild($processNameNode)
  [void]$exitProcessNode.AppendChild($forceCloseNode)

  # return new ExitProcess node
  return $exitProcessNode
}
```

Now that we've gotten that squared away, we just need to append this new subtree to `<ExitProcesses>`:

```
[xml]$xmlDocument = Get-Content .\path\to\document.xml

# Use XPath to retrieve the <ExitProcesses> node(s)
$xmlDocument |Select-Xml -XPath '//ExitProcesses' |ForEach-Object {
    # Create a new <ExitProcess> subtree with our function from above
    $newChild = New-ExitProcessNode -Document $xmlDocument -ProcessName "Test.exe"

    # Append to <ExitProcesses>
    [void]$_.Node.AppendChild($newChild)
}
```

`$xmlDocument` is now updated with your new `<ExitProcess>` node and you can save it with:

```
$xmlDocument.Save("$PWD\path\to\output.xml")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will try it out as soon as I can. It's easier to understand when you have an example like this