# Adding an xml fragment to an existing document

Tags: xml, powershell

What is the *least effort* way to insert an xml fragment into an existing `[xml]` value (`[xml]` of course is syntactic sugar for `System.Xml.XmlDocument`)?

For example, say we have this newrelic.config file:

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:newrelic-config" agentEnabled="true">
  <service licenseKey="**redacted**" />
  <application>
    <name>My Application</name>
  </application>
  <log level="info" />
  <transactionTracer enabled="true" transactionThreshold="apdex_f" stackTraceThreshold="500" recordSql="obfuscated" explainEnabled="false" explainThreshold="500" />
  <crossApplicationTracer enabled="true" />
  <errorCollector enabled="true">
    <ignoreErrors>
      <exception>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</exception>
      <exception>System.Threading.ThreadAbortException</exception>
    </ignoreErrors>
    <ignoreStatusCodes>
      <code>401</code>
      <code>404</code>
    </ignoreStatusCodes>
  </errorCollector>
  <browserMonitoring autoInstrument="true" />
  <threadProfiling>
    <ignoreMethod>System.Threading.WaitHandle:InternalWaitOne</ignoreMethod>
    <ignoreMethod>System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitAny</ignoreMethod>
  </threadProfiling>
</configuration>
```

And we want to insert an `instrumentation` node under `configuration`; not just one element but a whole fragment:

```
  <instrumentation>
    <applications>
      <application name="MyApplication.exe" />
    </applications>
  </instrumentation>
```

Most other answers on SO flail around a lot with creating XML elements and attributes; for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66723564/864696):

```
 # Create ExitProcess node
  $exitProcessNode = $Document.CreateElement('ExitProcess')

  # Create ProcessName node, add process name as inner text
  $processNameNode = $Document.CreateElement('ProcessName')
  $processNameNode.InnerText = $ProcessName

  # Create ForceClose node, add setting as inner text 
  $forceCloseNode = $Document.CreateElement('ProcessName')
  $ForceCloseNode.InnerText = $ForceClose.IsPresent
```

How can I make this shorter?

Note: I don't have huge documents so performance is not really an issue; I'm more after shorter PowerShell code.

Comment: @iRon Oops. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to import the node ([`ImportNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode)) in the main document and than append the concerned child ([`AppendChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild)) to the specific node:

```
$Main = [xml]'
<configuration xmlns="urn:newrelic-config" agentEnabled="true">
  <service licenseKey="**redacted**" />
  <application>
    <name>My Application</name>
  </application>
  <log level="info" />
  <transactionTracer enabled="true" transactionThreshold="apdex_f" stackTraceThreshold="500" recordSql="obfuscated" explainEnabled="false" explainThreshold="500" />
  <crossApplicationTracer enabled="true" />
  <errorCollector enabled="true">
    <ignoreErrors>
      <exception>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</exception>
      <exception>System.Threading.ThreadAbortException</exception>
    </ignoreErrors>
    <ignoreStatusCodes>
      <code>401</code>
      <code>404</code>
    </ignoreStatusCodes>
  </errorCollector>
  <browserMonitoring autoInstrument="true" />
  <threadProfiling>
    <ignoreMethod>System.Threading.WaitHandle:InternalWaitOne</ignoreMethod>
    <ignoreMethod>System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitAny</ignoreMethod>
  </threadProfiling>
</configuration>'

$Fragment = [xml]'
  <instrumentation>
    <applications>
      <application name="MyApplication.exe" />
    </applications>
  </instrumentation>'
```

```
$NewNode = $Main.ImportNode($Fragment.instrumentation, $True)
$Main.Configuration.AppendChild($NewNode)
```

```
[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($Main.OuterXml).ToString()

<configuration xmlns="urn:newrelic-config" agentEnabled="true">
  <service licenseKey="**redacted**" />
  <application>
    <name>My Application</name>
  </application>
  <log level="info" />
  <transactionTracer enabled="true" transactionThreshold="apdex_f" stackTraceThreshold="500" recordSql="obfuscated" explainEnabled="false" explainThreshold="500" />
  <crossApplicationTracer enabled="true" />
  <errorCollector enabled="true">
    <ignoreErrors>
      <exception>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</exception>
      <exception>System.Threading.ThreadAbortException</exception>
    </ignoreErrors>
    <ignoreStatusCodes>
      <code>401</code>
      <code>404</code>
    </ignoreStatusCodes>
  </errorCollector>
  <browserMonitoring autoInstrument="true" />
  <threadProfiling>
    <ignoreMethod>System.Threading.WaitHandle:InternalWaitOne</ignoreMethod>
    <ignoreMethod>System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitAny</ignoreMethod>
  </threadProfiling>
  <instrumentation xmlns="">
    <applications>
      <application name="MyApplication.exe" />
    </applications>
  </instrumentation>
</configuration>
```

As commented by [**Ross Presser**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864696/ross-presser); text nodes are returned as strings by the PowerShell accelerated `[Xml]` parser and therefore might cause problem if the parent node or a child node is a text node. This implementation is essential incorrect and noted here: [`#16878` Decorate dot selected Xml strings (leaves) with XmlElement methods](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16878). If you want to ensure that the (leaf) node you select is always an `XmlElement`, you might do something like:

```
$Fragment.instrumentation.applications.SelectSingleNode('application')
```

Comment: OMG that is indeed so much better. Thank you @iron

Comment: Your solution breaks when the fragment I want to add is a single element `<labels />` or `<labels></labels>` or even `<labels>foo:bar</labels>`. I suppose the argument is that if the fragment is just an element, then use `CreateElement()`, that's what it's for. Sigh. I wanted to use a single style throughout. But it does make sense.

Comment: and I now realize that reason it "breaks" is because I was *relying* on the deep-element-property thing always returning an XmlElement. That's not always true -- if the element has no attributes or subelements, it returns a string (the InnerText value). That's by design in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

This function appends a `string` xml fragment as a child of an `xmlelement`:

```
function AppendChildXml {
     param (
         [System.Xml.XmlElement]$element,
         [string]$fragment
     )
     [System.Xml.XmlDocumentFragment]$fragxml = $element.OwnerDocument.CreateDocumentFragment();
     $fragxml.innerXml = $fragment;
     $element.AppendChild($fragxml);
}
```

Since the function has an `XmlElement` as its first parameter, this makes it easy to mix with the "PowerShell way" of referring to deep elements with properties, e.g. `$xmldoc.configuration.errorCollector.ignoreErrors`

For example:

```
# read in the existing newrelic.config
[xml]$newRelicConfigXml = [xml]::new();
$newRelicConfigXml.Load((Convert-Path $newRelicConfigPath));

# instrumentation section to be added
[string]$fragment = '<instrumentation><applications><application name="MyApplication.exe"/></applications></instrumentation>'

# add instrumentation under configuration
AppendChildXml $newRelicConfigXml.configuration $fragment
```